# Yammer JavaScript API erroneously throwing an error for an empty 200 response?

Tags: javascript, yammer

I am unable to post an activity from the [Yammer JavaScript library](https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/js-sdk). When I use `yam.request` the error callback is returned with an [HTTP status code 200](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success).

If I try to use `yam.platform.request` I get:
`Origin https://3sharpepgdev03.sharepoint.com not found in Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.` I have this path in my JavaScript origins list in Yammer.

Here is the code in case you see something else wrong:

```
<script>
   function postActivity2() {
        yam.request({
            url: "activity.json",
            method: "POST",
            data: {
                "activity": {
                    "actor": {
                        "name": "Jeff Kirkham",
                        "email": "garthf@retailv3dev2.onmicrosoft.com"
                    },
                    "action": "create",
                    "object": {
                        "url": "https://3sharpepgdev03.sharepoint.com/Pages/Yammer%20Test%20Page.aspx",
                        "title": "Lunch Meeting"
                    },
                    "message": "Hey, let’s get sushi!",
                    "users": [
                    {
                        "name": "Jeff Kirkham",
                        "email": "garthf@retailv3dev2.onmicrosoft.com"
                    }
                    ]
                }
            },
            success: function (msg) { alert("Post was Successful!: " + msg); },
            error: function (msg) { console.dir(msg); }
        })
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I see the same problem, an empty 200 response appears to raise an error from Yammer. This is quite problematic in this circumstance.